# How to get Ember.js working?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm quite stuck and I don't know where I'm going wrong. I'm using the [Inspiritas](https://github.com/littke/inspiritas-bootstrap/) Bootstrap theme, and I wanted to use it in an Ember.js app.

I've been trying to read up, I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong - debugging didn't really help :(

My files are as follows:

#### app.js

```
app = Ember.Application.create();

app.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    name : "Hassan Khan"
});
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>app</title>
    <link href="inspiritas.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script src='../components/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/highcharts.com/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script src="../components/ember/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm not quite sure where the `application` bit should go, but here it is:

#### application.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="#">app</a>
            <span class="tagline">Blah</span>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse" id="main-menu">
                <div class="auth pull-right">
                    <img class="avatar" src="images/img.png">
                    <span class="name">{{ name }}</span><br/>
                    <span class="links">
                        <a href="#">Settings</a>
                        <a href="#">Logout</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9" id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                {{ outlet }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*application.html* needs to be compiled by `Ember.Handlebars`. If you put its content between `<script type="text/x-handlebars">` and `</script>` and place in the `head` or the `body` of your page, it will be automagically compiled and rendered for you.

It is also good practice to name your application variable `App`.

Your `name` should by moved to an `App.ApplicationController` if you want it to be rendered.

http://emberjs.com/guides would be a good starting point for creating an Ember Application. The new video from Tom Dale will definitely help you.

http://jsbin.com/aqokix/1

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it working in the end, sorry I took so long to reply :)